# How to Encrypt the Private Key in a Keystore file in Foundry

Tags: private-key, foundry, keystore

```
cast wallet import your-account-name --interactive
Enter private key:
Enter password:
`your-account-name` keystore was saved successfully. Address: address-corresponding-to-private-key
```

This was mentioned in Patrick Collin's Foundry Course.

I obtained "Address" from the above method.
But still having struggle how to use it, while doing

```
forge script <script> --rpc-url <rpc_url>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
forge script <script> --rpc-url <rpc_url> --account <account_name> --sender <address> --broadcast
```